# View not shown upon performSegueWithIdentifier

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, segue

So I have this splitview. On the left hand side you have the tableView. It has this plus sign. When I tap it I create a new managedObject Woman. I set a stored variable property on detailVC called woman. Then I segue from detailVC to editVC changing data. When I hit the plus sign everything works as it should.

When however I first select another woman in my tableView (showing her data on the detailVC) and then hit the plus I'm not seguing. Anyone know why?

Code:

```
self.detailViewController!.woman = woman
self.detailViewController?.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext
self.detailViewController?.performSegueWithIdentifier("editWomanSegue", sender: self.detailViewController!)
```

I looked in the prepareForSegue of the detailVC. In prepareForSegue of detailVC I'm doing:
Code:

```
let editVC = segue.destinationViewController as! EditWomanViewController
editVC.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext
editVC.woman = self.woman
```

I put a print on the setting of the woman stored variable property in editWomanVC and yes it is set. Only problem is the View is not shown or loaded (viewDidLoad isn't called for) :s

Answer (score 0):

I might have found the solution. I have it running now. I solved it by first performing a segue from the masterVC to the detailVC. In the detailVC I'm performing again a segue to the editWomanVC when an attribute of woman is empty in the detailVC. This works. I still wonder why I could not perform a segue on the detailVC with

```
       self.detailViewController?.performSegueWithIdentifier("editWomanSegue", sender: self.detailViewController!)
```

though.